# pdo and inserting json encoded to json field

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I was following this guide... [mysqltutorial.org/mysql-json](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-json/)

...and I decided to try theese concepts with PDO... but I must have lost something somewhere.

THIS works perfectly:

```
$db = new PDO ("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$array=array(1=>array(2=>'kkk',3=>'pizza'));
$json= json_encode($array); 

$db->query("INSERT INTO test(config) VALUES('".$json."');");
```

BUT THIS DON'T:

```
$db = new PDO ("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$array=array(1=>array(2=>'kkk',3=>'pizza'));
$json= json_encode($array); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (config) VALUES(':config');";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':config', $json, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
```

The second one returns this error:

```
SQLSTATE[22032]: <>: 3140 Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 0 in value for column 'test.config'.
```

var_dump on $json:

```
page.php:18:string '{"1":{"2":"kkk","4":"pizza"}}' (length=29)
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't put quotes around placeholders. If you quote it, it tries to insert that literal string, instead of replacing it with the value from `bindParam()`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (config) VALUES(:config);";
```

Comment: Mmm...the statement was pasted from another guide, I've tried to remove the quotes from the placeholders before but nothing changed. Now I tried again and it works. Who knows what I did. Thank you!